# Search function within our website using jsp and mysql

Tags: mysql, function, jsp, search

I am having troubled coding the search function for my website where i understand that we had to use the method call LIKE to search but till now i have no idea how it work. Can someone do a example using jsp and mysql to do a search function. Thanks.

Comment: At least try something and post your code if you have any error. Refer https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some many sites if your are looking of complete code
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm

```
 <sql:setDataSource var="DBNAME" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
         user="root"  password="password"/>

    <sql:query dataSource="${DBNAME}" var="result">
    SELECT * from TABLENAME where column_name like '%ames';
    </sql:query>
```